# Java Type Inference With Streams And Raw Types

Tags: java, type-inference

I have the following java class:

```
public class Test {

    public static void doThings() {

        List<WrappedTypeContainer> things = Stream.of(new ExampleType())
            .map(Type::toValue)
            .map(WrappedTypeContainer::new)
            .collect(Collectors.toList());
    }

    public static class WrappedType<T extends Type<T>> {

        T value;

        public WrappedType(T value) {
            this.value = value;
        }

        public static WrappedType of(Type value) {
            return new WrappedType(value);
        }
    }

    public interface Type<T extends Type<T>> {

        default WrappedType toValue() {
            return WrappedType.of(this);
        }

    }

    public static class ExampleType implements Type<ExampleType> {}

    public static class WrappedTypeContainer {

        WrappedType<ExampleType> wrappedValue;

        public WrappedTypeContainer(WrappedType<ExampleType> wrappedValue) {
            this.wrappedValue = wrappedValue;
        }

    }

}
```

This code doesn't compile. I know what the problem is, its that the `toValue()` method is returning a raw type instead of the correctly typed parameter. If I change that the code will compile.

As far as I understand it should just be casting this to the expected type at runtime and not be failing at compile time. Is my understanding correct or is it correct that compilation should fail. If so, can someone please explain to me why this doesn't work as is, and whether or not this is a bug in the compiler?

I am currently compiling with Java build 1.8.0_102-b14. However I have tried on other newer version as well.

Comment: Hmmmmm, I realise the point that I'm trying to make is lost because I over simplified the example. Let me edit the question.

Comment: Your code works fine in java version "10.0.1" 2018-04-17.

Comment: @Radiodef I've updated the code. So here is the weird thing, I have a class thats wrapping my parameterized type in this case, its receiving the raw type in its constructor, this however is fine, but later it infers this wrapping class to object. Why?

Comment: @Radiodef also, I've already fixed this in my actual code to do away with the raw types, the question is more out of curiosity as to why it works this way rather than wondering how to fix it.

Comment: Seeing your edit, this could be a bug, I guess. I was able to produce a more minimal example: https://ideone.com/d79qIv. The type of the `collect` method is getting erased for some reason. As saka is saying above, it compiles in newer versions.